# Bokeh Tooltips on annular wedge : extra information always present

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I have created the following doughnut chart in bokeh, using `annular_wedge` glyphs. I've created a tooltip, that shows percents & category properly for each wedge, but always includes an extra `category : ???` and `percents:1`

Why is it appearing, and how can I remove it ?

Here's a link to the notebook used for generating the plot : [link](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/knightofni/801d8773d0bb0a85888b)

[image]

```
# define starts/ends for wedges from percentages of a circle
percents = [0, 0.14, 0.22, 0.40, 0.83, 0.99, 1.0]
category = ['Extreme ', 'High ', 'Light ', 'Medium ', 'Not Classified', 'Very Light ']
starts = [p*2*pi for p in percents[:-1]]
ends = [p*2*pi for p in percents[1:]]

# a color for each pie piece
colors = brewer['Spectral'][len(percents)]

# create source
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=[0 for x in percents],
        y=[0 for x in percents],
        ymin = [0.5 for x in percents],
        ymax = [1 for x in percents],
        percents=percents,
        category= category,
        starts=starts,
        colors=colors,
        ends=ends,
    )
)

# create chart
TOOLS = "hover"
p = bk.figure(title='Chronic',title_text_font ='Roboto', title_text_font_size ='14pt', title_text_alpha =0.7,
              x_range=(-1.1,1.1), y_range=(-1.1,1.1), width=250, height=250, tools=TOOLS)

p.annular_wedge(x='x', y='y',  inner_radius='ymin', outer_radius='ymax', direction="anticlock",
                start_angle='starts', end_angle='ends', color='colors', source=source)

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [
    ('category', '@category'),
    ('percents','@percents')
]

# displays
bk.show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting these values directly in the function call:

```
p.annular_wedge(x=0, y=0, inner_radius=0.5, outer_radius=1, ... )
```